# A matching that covers vertices with maximum degree

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory, subgraph

We have a graph G with maximum degree $\Delta$. The induced subgraph on vertices with degree equal to $\Delta$ is a bipartite graph (while the original graph is not).
Prove that G has a matching that covers all vertices with degree $\Delta$.

For example consider $K_{3,3}$ and add a vertex on one edge. So the graph has 7 vertices and 10 edges. The graph is not bipartite, but the induced subgraph on vertices with degree $\Delta(G) = 3$ is a bipartite subgraph. You can easily find a matching that covers all of the 6 vertices with degree 3.

Comment: "Prove that ...": why do you know the assertion is true? -- Is this an exercise?

Comment: duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638598/any-bipartite-graph-has-a-matching-that-covers-each-vertex-of-maximum-degree

Comment: @ChrisGodsil As far as I can tell, this question is more general.  Am I missing something?

Comment: It's formally more general, but all you really need is that the union of the matchings covering the two classes of maximum degree vertices is a union of paths and _even_ cycles, so bipartiteness only matters on this induced subgraph.

Comment: @BenBarber But what about the case of paths with an *even* number of edges?  For example, the matching covering $A$ might use an edge $ac$ and the matching covering $B$ might use an edge $bc$ with $c \notin A \cup B$.

Comment: @StefanKohl Yes and No! It was an exercise of a graduate course, but I wasn't solve by the students in the time, and the teacher doesn't seem to know the answer and asked the student to search for it!

Comment: ChrisGodsil and @BenBarber The question is more general and the proposed solution for that, doesn't work for the example that I mentioned above ($K_{3,3}+v$). As TonyHuynh mentioned, a vertex (v in the example) can be in both matchings and produce a path of length even (in the example) two, in this case the matching cannot be corrected.
One of my ideas was to remove the corrupted matching (find and remove a subgraph $H$ of $G$ that each vertex with maximum degree in $G$ has degree 1 in $H$ and other vertices have degree 0,1 or 2) and reduce the $\Delta$ by one and use induction afterward!

Comment: @Tony Huynh: You are correct, it is more general.

Comment: @TonyHuynh   , after removing all edges which appear in both matchings (which do not interact with the rest of the edges), _every_ path has at least one external vertex, so paths split and have an endpoint that you don't care about.

Comment: @BenBarber Please check my comment for you answer.

Comment: I am persuaded that this is more complicated than I thought.  Sorry for the noise!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We use Tutte's theorem: if a graph $G$ with even number of vertices does not have a perfect matching, then there exists a set $S\subset V(G)$ such that the graph $G\setminus S$ has at least $|S|+2$ odd components.

Let $V=M\sqcup U$ be a vertex set, where $M$ is the set of vertices with maximal degree $\Delta$. We prove that if the induced subgraph $G(M)$ is bipartite, then
there exists a matching covering $M$. Add new set $W$,
$|W|=|M|+|U|$, of vertices to our graph, join 
them with each other and with all vertices of $U$. We have to prove that
in the new graph there exists a perfect matching. Assume the contrary,
then by the Tutte theorem there exists a set $S$ of vertices such that $G\setminus S$ has at least $|S|+2$ odd components. 
If $W\subset S$, it is a clear nonsense. Thus in $G\setminus S$ all vertices
of $(U\cup W)\setminus S$ are in the same component, hence there
exist at least $|S|+1$ odd components containing only vertices of
$M$. Consider each such odd component $K$. It is bipartite graph having, say, 
$k$ vertices in larger part and $\leq k-1$ vertices in a smaller part. 
Totally $\Delta k$ edges of $G$ go from the larger part of $K$. Between them, at most
$\Delta(k-1)$ edges go to the smaller part of $K$, hence at least $\Delta$ edges go outside $K$. 
They all go to $S$. Summing up by all odd components of $G\setminus S$ which belong to $M$ we see that at least $\Delta(|S|+1)$ edges from them come to $S$, it is impossible.

Comment: Very nice argument!  I added more details, but then decided it was better the way it was before.

Comment: The Tutte's condition is $\forall S \subseteq V, o(G\backslash S)\le|S|$, so the reverse is $\exists S \subseteq V, o(G\backslash S) > |S|$ or $o(G\backslash S) \ge |S|+1$, not $o(G\backslash S) \ge |S|+2$.

Comment: If graph has even number of vertices, then $o(G\setminus S)+|S|$ is always even.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Yes, You are right.
What about the situation when two parts have the same number of vertices $k$?

Comment: Then it is not very much odd, right?

Comment: That's right. I misread the definition of $K$.
Beautiful solution! I marked it as a correct answer. Thank you.